# what is my syntax error here in mySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `creditors` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `route` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `mobile` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `credit_amount` double(100) NOT NULL,
    `start_date` date NOT NULL,
    `due_date` date NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY `idUnique` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

`MySQL` said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') NOT NULL,
>        `start_date` date NOT NULL,
>        `due_date` date NOT NULL,    ' at line 6

What is my syntax error in this SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a Column to `primary key`, it consists only Unique value. Then why did you try to made the same to `UNIQUE KEY`?

And also Delete the `RANGE` for `Double`.

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66c92)

```
CREATE TABLE `creditors` (
    `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `route` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `mobile` int NOT NULL,
    `credit_amount` double NOT NULL,
    `start_date` date NOT NULL,
    `due_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL,
    `start_date` date NOT NULL,
    `due_date` date NOT NULL
) EN' at line 6

Comment: @SampathMahadewa, Try now.

Comment: @SampathMahadewa, You are welcome. Accept the answer, this may help someone

Answer (score 0):

The error is with this statement:

```
`credit_amount` double(100) NOT NULL
```

Give precision after 100 in double data type.

Solution:

```
 `credit_amount` double(100,0) NOT NULL
```

Instead of `0` after `100` give number of digits after decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `double` you must specify both `M` and `D` where 
`M` is number digits in total, of which `D` digits may be after the decimal point, i.e. `double(10,0)`. Otherwise use `float` which which allows syntax like `float(10)`.

Also, unless you really benefit from this, do not use `latin1` charset, but rather `UTF-8`